# powershell InternetExplorer.Application нажать на кнопку

Tags: powershell

Приветствую всех!

Столкнулся с задачей по внесению переменной во всплывающее окно prompt box.

Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>PS Prompt test</h2>

<button onclick="Function()" id="test">send value</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function Function() {
    var txt;
    var text = prompt("Please enter text:", "example text");
    if (text == null || text == "") {
        txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
    } else {
        txt = "Your text is: " + text;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Смог добраться только до его открытия:

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application;
$loginpage = "https://127.0.0.1/1/"
$ie.Navigate2($loginpage)
$ie.Visible = $true;
While ($ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100}
$ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("test").click()
```

Далее необходимо ввести любой текст во всплывшем окне и нажать на кнопку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если есть возможность помогите решить данную задачу.
Спасибо.

Comment: попробуйте `$ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("ваш ID, куда нужно текст вставить").value = txt;`

Comment: спасибо за совет, но тут как вы можете видеть в коде присутствует один id и при вставке $ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("demo").innerHTML = "тест тест тест" изменится значение между тегами "P" да и кнопка сама не нажмется)

Comment: тогда я не понял в чем проблема

Comment: необходимо ввести значение в открывшемся окне (заменить "example text" на любое другое значение. и затем нажать кнопку ок.

Comment: выполнение скрипта останавливается на моменте: $ie.document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementByID("test").click() и дальше ожидает действий от пользователя. Вот и нужно это как то автоматизировать.

Comment: тут просто приведен простейший пример, а так при нажатии на кнопку "ок" во всплывающем окне должно произойти событие по отправке  введенного значения методом POST на обработчик